# Geth (go-ethereum) uses 100% CPU during mining even with 1 thread is specified

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, mining, geth

**Steps to reproduce:**

Run geth with parameters
`--mine --minerthreads "1"`
or
`--mine --minerthreads 1`

**Expected behaviour:**

Only 1 thread is used.

**Actual behaviour:**

All CPU threads (8) are used with a 100% load.

**System information:**

Geth version: 1.9.6
OS & Version: Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 0):

It only limits the threads for mining, but your geth node is also syncing with other nodes, and this can occupy a huge amount of CPU resources.